# Set background-color on only the text not the empty space in a td

Tags: html, colors, background

I'm trying to get the background color to wrap around the text alone, not the empty spaces.

I now have:

```
<TD> Text <BR><BR>
Longer text that stretches out above text-background color...
</TD>
```

and css:

```
td {background-color: black; color: white}
```

The rest of the space I would like just to be transparant, but I can't find any variable for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try span as given below will do your work.....

```
<TD> <span> Text <BR><BR> Longer text that stretches out above text-background color... 
 </span></TD> 

span {background-color: black; color: white}
```

Comment: Well.. the span method works quite well, however, when i apply this to a sentence that doesn't fit on one line, and it goes to the second line, without using <BR> or anything, it will not indent the first word on the new line, like the padding/margin i set for the first word of the sentence.. but were getting closer...

Answer (score 3):

try `display:inline;` :

```
td {background-color: black; color: white; display:inline;}
```

Comment: Hm. It's never a good idea to change the display property of <td>, just for the sake of appearances!

Comment: same problem as above, the new line (of the same sentence) is not indented, and for my purpose (as a header) it doesn't work.. Especially when i put a <h3> tag in the span, it puts the header on another line entirely..

Answer (score 0):

Put a `<span>` around the text, and give that the background colour.